How can I detect if GameCenter login animation has completed?
I have an AR maze game recently uploaded to the App Store and it uses Game Center.
Until iOS 17, while developing, everything worked perfectly fine.
In iOS 18, there is some issue between GameKit and ARKit that didn't exist before:
If the GK Access Point is used (even if it's later hidden) before the AR camera is showing, the camera image will remain black thus no world tracking can take place. In other words the whole AR game is useless.
I opened FB14697134 on Apple for this issue (they tried to have me close it, but upon further discussions they reopened it).
So now, as a temporary workaround for iOS 18, I simply don't use the Access Point, which is a shame.  But I do authenticate into GameCenter as I want the user to continue to update the leaderboards and achievements and check on them through internal buttons I added in my Settings VC.
My remaining issue is that while the Game Center colorful login animation is taking place, if it happens while the AR Scene is already shown, everything freezes until that animation has completed and then everything goes back to normal.
If this animation happens quickly at the launch of the game because internet connection is fast (as on WiFi) then the whole thing will complete even before the user gets to the 3rd VC where the AR Scene is shown.
But if internet connection is slow, that animation may start when the AR Scene is already shown and then there are 2 cases: either the user has already started the game or not yet.

If the user didn't yet start the game, the camera image will in this case remain black and it will show the real world once the GC animation has completed.
So I added the following code to check if the AR Scene is capturing any image and the rest of the code to continue the game will only run in the completion block once the above has been confirmed:

func checkReadinessBeforeShowingMazeLevel(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        var count = 1
        
        var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
            if self.sceneView.session.currentFrame != nil {
                timer.invalidate()
                completion()
            }
            print("Waiting \(count)")
            count += 1
        }
    }

The count and printing I only added for debugging to see that it's indeed waiting a couple of seconds.
So this works.

But if internet connection is even slower and the user already started to play the game and suddenly the Game Center animation will start in the middle of the game, the whole game will freeze for some 8 seconds or more while the game timer will continue.
This is very bad game design and I'd want to avoid that (fortunately this should only happen once per game play or each time the game comes back into the foreground).

So the question is if anyone knows if there's a way to catch if the GK authentication animation has already run/completed or not?  I couldn't find a way to check it.
If there is a way to check this, I will add it to the above code and continue the game only in case we know that the GK animation has already completed (assuming there even is internet connection as if there is none the game should proceed without Game Center).
I tried checking:
if GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated

but this will return true even before the GC authentication animation has even started so it only shows an internal check that is not related to the animation which also freezes the AR Scene.
Thanks!
